# Getting error while parsing the column name from Excel file - using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, excel, calculated-columns

```
# Read the Excel file into a DataFrame
file_path = 'DA_Spreadsheet.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name= 0, header=None)

# Filter the DataFrame based on matching criteria
filtered_df = df[
    (df['Column1'] == 'a') &
    (df['Column23.date()'] > datetime.today().date() &
     df['Column23'] <= datetime.today().date())
]
```

I was expecting that the program would find all lines on `Column1`, where the cell on `Column1` had the value `'a'`, instead, I'm getting this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3652, in get_loc
        return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 147, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
      File "pandas\_libs\index.pyx", line 155, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
      File "pandas\_libs\index_class_helper.pxi", line 70, in pandas._libs.index.Int64Engine._check_type
    KeyError: 'Column1'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\***\rfsPython\emailBoss.py", line 40, in <module>
    check_excel_and_send_email(file_path, email_recipients)
  File "C:\Users\***\rfsPython\emailBoss.py", line 13, in check_excel_and_send_email
    filtered_df = df[(df['Column1'] == 'a') & (df['Column23.date()'] > datetime.today().date() & df['Column23'] <= datetime.today().date())]
                      ~~^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3761, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3654, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err
KeyError: 'Column1'
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the header of your Excel file/sheet ? Also, can you `print(df.columns)`  before using `df_filtered` ?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please read How to Ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, and add some info about what you are trying to do in your question body

Answer (score 0):

The error message suggests that pandas cannot find a column called 'Column1' in your DataFrame. Double-check the column headers in your Excel file to make sure they match the names you are using in your code. If the column name is spelled correctly and you still get the error, try specifying the header row in your code using the `header` parameter when reading the Excel file:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=0, header=0)
```

This assumes the headers are on the first row of the Excel sheet. Additionally, make sure that the column name 'Column23.date()' is properly formatted and matches the actual column name in your Excel file. If it contains a function call, try removing it and referencing the column directly:

```
(df['Column23'] > datetime.today().date() & df['Column23'] <= datetime.today().date())
```

Remember that column names are case-sensitive, so check that you are using the correct capitalization as well. With these changes, your code should filter the DataFrame correctly without raising a KeyError.